# ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 7

Tags: sql, mysql, database, data-structures

I'm trying to move my old phpBB forum database to my new server. So when I donwloaded the .sql file I tried uploading it to a new database via a phpMyAdmin panel. Here is the error I recieved:

```
<pre>Error

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 7
STR: />
SQL: 

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at webiste/includes/acp/acp_database.php:593) in <b>website/includes/functions.php</b> on line <b>3582</b><br />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>General Error</title><style type="text/css">
/* <![CDATA[ */
* { margin: 0;


SQL query:


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/24/d172572039/htdocs/GhostsofOnyx/includes/acp/acp_database.php:593) in /homepages/24/d172572039/htdocs/GhostsofOnyx/includes/functions.php on line 3582<code>
```

What do I need to change or fix to be able to fully upload the file? Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

On line 7 you have

`* { margin: 0;`

The `;` symbol delineates the end of a SQL query. Obviously, in this case if that's the end of the query the server does not know what to do, hence the error.

You need to specify a new delimiter (I often use `|`) so that phpMyAdmin knows when the script is complete.